# Undefined symbol for HDF5 when installing with cmake in Linux environment

Tags: cmake, linker, static-libraries, hdf5

I have been able to install and start a program with CMake (with HDF5) but once I access the "about" drop-down link for said program it crashes with the following error:

```
python: symbol lookup error: /nobackup/<user id>/program-devel/dist_linux/bin_linux/libprogramDLL.so: undefined symbol: h5lib_MP_h5get_libversion_f_
```

I believe it is an issue with linking static libraries but I am, unfortunately, quite new to CMake and unable to isolate the root problem. I know that this "symbol" is tied somehow to a `libhdf5_fortran.a` and this is listed in my Cache with:

```
   $ grep -rnw '/nobackup/<user id>/program-devel/build' -e "libhdf5_fortran"
/nobackup/<user id>/program-devel/build/CMakeCache.txt:234:ToolkitLib_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;SomeLib;general;libz.a;general;libhdf5.a;general;libhdf5_fortran.a;
```

I’m not sure if this might be where the problem is or not but this is from the ToolKit file - CMakeLists.txt.

```
if (${USE_HDF5})
      #link_directories (${HDF5_DIRECTORY}/lib)
      if (WIN32)
          target_link_libraries(ToolkitLib libszip libzlib libhdf5 libhdf5_f90cstub libhdf5_fortran)
      else ()

            # doesn't seem to work on Linux for some reason....
          #target_link_libraries(ToolkitLib libsz libz libhdf5 libhdf5_fortran)

          # ... try this ... seems to be getting the shared libs...not the static ones...
          # set(HDF5_LINK_FLAGS "-L${HDF5_DIRECTORY}/lib -lz -lhdf5_fortran -lhdf5")
          # SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${HDF5_LINK_FLAGS}")
          # SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${HDF5_LINK_FLAGS}")

            # ... doesn't work either ...
          target_link_libraries(ToolkitLib libz.a libhdf5.a libhdf5_fortran.a)

      endif()
endif()
```

The last 4 "target_link_library" elements are in directories I've added to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (although, I've heard this isn't the preferred approach). There is also a final output line when I issue `gmake install` that might be relevant:

```
    -- Set runtime path of "/nobackup/<user id>/program-devel/dist_linux/bin_linux/libProgramDLL.so" to "$ORIGIN/"
```

Comment: cmake provide the function `FindHDF5` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindHDF5.html After successful finding of HDF5, add `include_directories(${CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY} ${HDF5_Fortran_INCLUDE_DIRS})` once and 
`target_link_libraries(ToolkitLib ${HDF5_Fortran_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})` for the library. If HDF5 is not in a standard location, use `export HDF5_ROOT=/path/to/hdf5` *before* invoking cmake.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on course! I'm seeing where `HDF5_Fortran_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `HDF5_Fortran_LIBRARIES` are getting defined by the FindHDF5 but do I set the `CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY` and `CMAKE_DL_LIBS` manually? Also, I'm seeing a preferred method (or perhaps, the same thing) as `FindHDF5` by providing a command like `find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS Fortran NO_MODULE REQUIRED static)`. Are these, in fact, the same?

Comment: I actually always define `CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY` but you are right: it should not be needed. Without `CMAKE_DL_LIBS` I had build problems on linux with certains combinations of cmake and hdf5. I think it is not the default to include them for Fortran but the `-ldl` flag is needed for the dynamic binding at least. For static versions it should not be needed.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I'm running into a problem of the config file cannot be found. I've searched in the install directory, my programs' build and src directories but it doesn't exist. `CMake Error at Toolkit/CMakeLists.txt:101 (find_package):
   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "HDF5" with any of
   the following names:

     HDF5Config.cmake
     hdf5-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "HDF5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
   "HDF5_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.`

Comment: What version of cmake do you have?

Comment: 3.12.2, I'm trying to see if I can just start from scratch and follow the instructions on https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/cmakebuild.html

Comment: that should be recent enough. make sure that you reset the cache of cmake settings. In the build dir: `rm -r CMake*`. Then re-execute cmake. You don't need to build hdf5 with cmake to use the `FindHDF5` module, but you need to remove the `NO_MODULE` option.

Comment: I changed it to `find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS Fortran REQUIRED)` and it's finding the libraries (specifically the `libhdf5_fortran.a`) now but I'm back to the same problem where it crashes with the same error : `python: symbol lookup error: /nobackup/<user id>/program-devel/dist_linux/bin_linux/libprogramDLL.so: undefined symbol: h5lib_MP_h5get_libversion_f_`

Comment: In the HDF5 docs, I find `H5get_libversion_f` and not `h5get_libversion_f`. There might be some other error? By which I mean, an error the `libprogramDLL.so` code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I fixed my problem by adding a `--with-pic` on the hdf5 installation bash scripts. I also had to remove a `-standard-semantics` from the `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS` in the `src` directory. Those two things along with the help you provided fixed my problem. Thanks a lot Pierre de Buyl!